# How to pass params in React Query with custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am using react query with custom hook. I am unsure if the implementation is right. I want some suggestions.

This is my custom hook.

```
export const useMutationQuery = (
    { url, params = {} },
    options,
) => {
    return useMutation(() => createMutation({ url, params }), options);
};
```

and i am using the custom hook like this

```
  const { mutate } = useMutationQuery({
    url: 'url',
    params: data,
  });
```

It all works perfectly fine but when I call the mutate function I can't pass any params. Eg: mutate(data) instead of giving the params inside the useMutationQuery.

Problem is lot of times I am triggering the mutate function based on the data change which I feel it is very bad.

Can someone suggest me how can I use the mutate function like this mutate(data), with my custom hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `mutate` function itself can also take parameters. I would only pass static things to `useMutation`, and dynamic things that you don't know upfront, like data that the user inputs, via `mutate`:

```
export const useMutationQuery = (
    { url },
    options,
) => {
    return useMutation((params) => createMutation({ url, params }), options);
};
```

in the component:

```
function Component() {
  const { mutate } = useMutationQuery({
    url: 'url',
  });

  return (
    <MyForm onSubmit={data => mutate(data)} />
  )
}
```